# VBA Excel - Macscript causing problems on windows when using IIF

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a macro that opens a file that everyone has on their computer and in order to do so must know the person's username / work ID.
To get the person's work ID I've tried using the following:
`sso = IIf(InStr(Application.OperatingSystem, "Windows") = 1, Environ("UserName"), _
'MacScript("(user name as string)"))`

Running this on windows returns an error because of the Macscript (I think) and I'd assume the same would happen vice versa, even though the error part of the IIF is never actually accessed I'm guessing seeing as the whole line is executed this is why there is a problem, thus On Error Resume Next would not really help here.

I know this can be easily overcome by just using an if and else statement but I just want to know if I'm right / why this problem occurs and if there are any other more sophisticated ways of achieving what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IIF` function evaluates *both* the true and false parts, or rather it attempts to do so. There is no short-circuit. Your assumption about *why* it's failing (and also that you can't use an `OERN`) is correct.  You may take a look at conditional compilation logic, if certain parts of your code will not compile on Windows (or Mac, respectively).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240847(v=vs.60).aspx